# Google Firebase, Alert on register and login errors

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome, firebase-authentication, dom-events

Currently working on a login and registration system using google firebase for authentication. Login and register account functions are working. I have added a window alert if the user has been properly logged in and logged out. I am struggling with adding a window alert if the user is trying to register with an existing email or if the user enters an invalid email or password when trying to login. Here are my functions for registering and logging in:
What other code should/must I add to it in order to have the alert?

```
// signup
const signupForm = document.querySelector("#signup-form");
signupForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // get user info
  const email = signupForm["signup-email"].value;
  const password = signupForm["signup-password"].value;

  // sign up the user
  auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => {
    // close the signup modal & reset form
    const modal = document.querySelector("#modal-signup");
    M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();
    signupForm.reset();
  });
});
```

```
// login
const loginForm = document.querySelector("#login-form");
loginForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // get user info
  const email = loginForm["login-email"].value;
  const password = loginForm["login-password"].value;

  // log the user in
  auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => {
    // close the signup modal & reset form
    const modal = document.querySelector("#modal-login");
    M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();
    loginForm.reset();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use `then()` `catch()` to check the errors callback

firebase have a list of general errors codes, see more here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors

example

```js
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => {
  // close the signup modal & reset form
  const modal = document.querySelector("#modal-login");
  M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();
  loginForm.reset();
}).then(() => {
  // do something
}).catch((error) => {
  if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
     alert('email already in use!');
  } else if (error.code === 'auth/network-request-failed') {
      alert('without network connection!');
  } else if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
      alert('invalid E-mail!');
      // email wrong format
  }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much :)